# How to generate xml test report with stdout of unittest?

Tags: python, xml, unit-testing, junit

Assume I have a python tool to build and run `unittest`, e.g. `python3 build_and_test ...`.

Is there any way to parse stdout of `unittest` and generate xml(junit) report? I have refer to `unittest-xml-reporting`, but it seems that I must change my `build_and_test` code and I can't do that. How can I just parse the stdout of `unittest` and create xml reports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take 2 steps:

1. Extend unittest.TextTestRunner and override _makeResult(). See https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/unittest.html#unittest.TextTestRunner._makeResult
2. Implement your own version of unittest.TestResult. See https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestResult. Your code will be code upon various events. Example: When there is a testing error the methid addError will be called. See https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestResult.addError

Now you have control of the various events and you will be able to create the XML report.